# JSOM: Limit calls to SP.ClientContext executeQueryAsync with promises (Angular example)

Tags: javascript, jsom, promises

I have asked myself this question several times before:

> Is it possible to have a JavaScript function used multiple times from multiple locations returning a promise calling `ctx.executeQueryAsync`, but only doing a single request to server from browser?

This is not the same as just wrapping `executeQueryAsync` in a promise, as that would possibly result in multiple requests to server.
It is also the opposite of a normal `Q.all`-function which waits for several promises to finish. Instead I want to wait for one single promise to finish then call out to a random amount of "listeners".

The reason I post an answer to my own question is because I haven't seen it come up before, and I find it really neat and a nice-to have solution which I want to share.

Answer (score 1):

My starting point is to have one shared instance of `SP.ClientContext`. I'm going to augment the object instance so using `new` keyword is preferable:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
```

The basic theory is to create a method `execThen` returning a promise, called when `executeQueryAsync` finishes, but only once for each "listener".
Something like this:

### Usage

```
ctx.load(ctx.get_web());

ctx.execThen().then(function() {
  console.log(ctx.get_web());
});

ctx.load(ctx.get_site());

ctx.execThen().then(function() {
  console.log(ctx.get_site());
});
```

The code above will issue **one single** call to `executeQueryAsync`, even though `execThen` is called twice (in separate locations, could be separate files). If a new `execThen` was made *inside* of another `execThen` there would be a new call to `executeQueryAsync`, e.g.,

```
ctx.execThen().then(ctx.execThen);
```

Any promise-based library should support this, such as jQuery, Angular or Q.
As an example; here is my current implementation in Angular:

### Angular example

```
ctx.execThen = (function () {
  var q;
  return function () {
    if (!q) {
      q = $q.when().then(function () {
        return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
          ctx.executeQueryAsync(resolve, reject);
        }).then(function () {
          q = null;
        });
      });
    }
    return q;
  };
})();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can see the value/usefulness of this. Can you please provide a broader context/scenario/example that let us better understand where you find this can be useful?

Comment: @eirikb, i have to agree with MdMazzotti, could you please explain a little bit with a more realistic example?

Comment: @MdMazzotti  Consider [this code](https://gist.github.com/eirikb/0a35dd446801e5a3bfe2) could render something [like this](http://i.imgur.com/P5sS1bm.png), but only make one single [browser request](http://i.imgur.com/N44IRlV.png)

Comment: @eirkb Maybe I'm missing something, but what I still don't get is the timing. When exactly does executeQueryAsync get called and why? From the code, I can see you return a new promise the first time the execThen function is called; all subsequent calls get the same promise. What if executeAsync is run before a later call to .load is made?

Comment: @MdMazzotti The first call to `execThen` will create only one promise which will be returned on subsequent calls. Because of the additional `.when()` the call to `executeQueryAsync` will not be issued until the next Angular $digest cycle. So with the cost of a tiny delay it's possible to add `.load`-calls directly after `execThen`.

Comment: Here is another example of __two levels__ (Fetching first user and first group for that user, and first list with first item for that list): [Code](https://gist.github.com/eirikb/92db02b9bcf3dfc8b3e2), [Rendered](http://i.imgur.com/coTx0D0.png), [Requests](http://i.imgur.com/ke8kfLq.png)

Comment: Now I got it, thanks. This is very specific to Angular though, and its $digest cycle. If this weren't used along with Angular (eg. in any other standard "procedural" code), then this wouldn't work, or would it?

Comment: @MdMazzotti no I don't think it would directly, but with some change it should be possible. I'm a bit reluctant to say so, but perhaps with a `setTimeout(function(){...});`, or perhaps a trick with promises

Comment: Yep, you confirmed my doubts. Btw, I would stay away from a dirty trick like the use of setTimeout